# Optimize a double list comprehension in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to optimize list comprehension?

```
[item for ctaken in courses_taken for item in ctaken.valid_course_numbers(req)]
```

I tried using map and filter but that took more time and was doing what I wanted.

```
list(itertools.chain(*map(lambda x: x.valid_course_numbers(req), courses_taken)))
```

This is slower than list comprehension.

The problem is my applications is hitting a bottle neck at this location. This piece of code is being called a lot. I want to shave a few seconds here. Which will make a huge impact.

Comment: have you an example ? input and output ?

Comment: The list comprehension seems fine to me, why do you think it should be optimized? Any further optimization might be limited to what you’re trying to do and what you’re using, so providing a **minimal complete verifiable example** will help.

Comment: Well, in some scenarios `iterators` tend to be faster than list comprehensions, but choosing iterators over list comp depends on many things!

Comment: "This piece of code is being called a lot." Does that mean in each run of your code you are running that same double list comp multiple times, with different values for `courses_taken` and/or `req`? What are you doing with the list once it's built?

Comment: Yes I am running the same piece of code with different values of courses_taken and req. After that I use that list to compare values individually.

Comment: A list comprehension is about as optimized as you are going to get for this operation. `map` + `lambda` is almost always marginally slower (except for built-in functions).  BTW, you should use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` instead of splatting a `map`. But regardless, you should likely take a look at the algorithm in `ctaken.valid_course_numbers` if you are trying to optimize this...

Comment: If all else fails, you can convert the bottleneck parts to perform at C speeds using the techniques described in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdeMlNiX2VSR1lFRHM/view